# Upload image to server crashes in Galaxy S3 but works fine for other Devices

Tags: android, image, amazon-s3, galaxy

I have developed an Android app that uploads image from device Gallery to server. It works fine other devices expect Galaxy S3. My Galaxy S2 works fine, though S2 and S3 has same os Jelly Bean.

In S3 during uploading Image app crashes. Not sure whats the wrong? Here is the code to upload  an image:

```
if (selectedImagePath.length() != 0) {

            // get data from page

            try
            {

                BitmapFactory.Options opts=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                opts.inSampleSize = 4;  

                Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath,opts);

                System.gc();

                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


                // Resize the image
                double width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
                double height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
                double ratio = 300 / width;
                int newheight = (int) (ratio * height);

                // System.out.println("———-width" + width);
                // System.out.println("———-height" + height);

                bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg,400,
                        newheight, true);  // 400 chilo age

                // Here you can define .PNG as well
                bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,75, bao);

                byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                String ba1 = ImageConverter.encodeBytes(ba);

                // System.out.println("uploading image now ——–” + ba1);

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", ba1));

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("event_id",
                        Integer.toString(taskEntity.getEventId())));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description",
                        description));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("urgent", Integer
                        .toString(urgentAttention)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sendtime",
                        convertedtime));

                try {

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            AppSettings.SERVER_ADDRESS+"upload_image.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                            nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    // print responce
                    outPut = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    Log.i("GET RESPONSE—-", outPut);

                    // is = entity.getContent();
                    Log.e("log_tag ******", "good connection");

                    bitmapOrg.recycle();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag ******",
                            "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't indicate what error you are receiving, but since your problem is specific to the Galaxy S3 I'm guessing it's an OutOfMemoryError.  The S3 tends to have small app heaps relative to its screen size so bitmap storage is a little tight.

Try using:

```
opts.inPurgeable = true;
opts.inInputShareable = true;
```

inPurgeable will allocate the bitmap on a different heap and allow its data to be discarded under memory pressure without waiting for the garbage collector.  inInputShareable will allow the bitmap to be re-decoded from the specified input in case it is purged before you are done with it.  It's good practice to use these two options as often as possible.  Just remember that with inInputShareable the data being decoded can't be changed or discarded because the Bitmap may need it again.